# Historical reference request: Young tableaux

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, math-history, young-tableaux

I am writing up an article on the RSK correspondence. To this end, I want to understand the history behind the invention of the Young tableaux and how it was introduced into the study of the symmetry group by Frobenius.

> Could someone point me towards some articles/books that talk about this particular historical development (excluding Curtis's book *Pioneers of Representation Theory* and Lam's article in the Notices).

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for "I am writing up an article on the RSK correspondence."

Comment: @darijgrinberg: :-).. it was all very hush-hush.

Answer (score 3):

Gian-Carlo Rota's entertaining *Indiscrete Thoughts* (Birkhäuser 2008), although primarily about Princeton mathematics from 1950 to 1990, devotes six pages to Alfred Young, including the history you're interested in -- it's more dramatic than I would have thought.

I'll be interested to read your RSK history piece.  As someone interested in history of mathematics, could I ask if you know anything pertinent to [Fibonacci, compositions, history](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39898/fibonacci-compositions-history)?